# Why is this simple query taking more than 1 second?

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

The table has around 17M rows and is MyISAM.

```
select DateModified,PELTM,PSLTM 
from financial_key_ratios 
where SecurityId = 4525 
  and DateModified >= '2015-01-07';
```

This simple query seems to take more than 1 second a lot of times.

The indexes seem to be fine. Here is the output from explain:

```
 explain 
 select DateModified,PELTM,PSLTM 
 from financial_key_ratios 
 where SecurityId = 4525 
   and DateModified >= '2015-01-07';
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys                                  | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | financial_key_ratios | range | SecurityId,secid,DateModified_index,secid_date | secid_date | 7       | NULL |  156 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+------------------------------------------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

**What could we be doing wrong?**

```
CREATE TABLE `financial_key_ratios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SecurityId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PELTM` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `PSLTM` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `POCFLTM` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `PEG` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `PBV` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `EVEBTIDA` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Evbyrevenue` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Fcf_yeild` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Earnings_yeild` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Pe_annualized` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Pbys_annualized` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Pbybv_annualized` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Evbyebitda_annualized` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Evbyrevenue_annualized` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Pe_ltm_adj` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Enterprise_value` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `Marketcap` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `DividendYield` decimal(12,4) NOT NULL,
  `DateModified` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SecurityId` (`SecurityId`,`DateModified`),
  KEY `secid` (`SecurityId`),
  KEY `DateModified_index` (`DateModified`),
  KEY `secid_date` (`SecurityId`,`DateModified`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=65138826 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

**Update:**

I already have all the indexes in place. It is NOT always slow. Out of 14K requests, it is reported in slow query log around 100 times.

Here is the update from slow query log

```
Time=1.22s (68s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=249.2 (13955), 
select DateModified,PELTM,PSLTM from financial_key_ratios
where SecurityId = N and DateModified >= 'S'
```

Comment: That's quite generic without further details. What else is going on on the server? Is it a dedicated MySQL server? How big the database? Does it fit to RAM? What is the underlying disk subsystem? Are there other concurrent queries? Is the query always slow or only occasionally? Explain is only a first step and doesn't tell anything about how long a query could take to execute.

Comment: 1 sec for a range in 17 millions rows doesnt seem that much to me.

Comment: Since you already have the `SecurityId` index, the `sec_id` index is redundant. You should drop it. You could probably get rid of the `secid` index as well. But that is unrelated to the question. Anyway, 100 out of 14K requests is less than 1%. And 1 sec is not that slow (how many rows are returned in the slow cases)?

Comment: @rational-space check the slow log entries - they should contain info about rows examined and lock times among others - the table is MyISAM so there are table locks on updates. A mix of few heavy selects and updates intertwined may cause parallelism to go out the window and the query just waiting to be executed for most of the time.

Comment: What are the `N` and `'S'` from the log entry? Is that a real query with wrong values or some placeholders? Comparing a `DATE` column to `'S'` would lead to a full table scan but probably no results..

Comment: Just place holders.

Comment: `SecurityId`, `secid` and `secid_date` are redundant. Save CPU, I/O and space by keeping only the first one. If the data you're trying to fetch is spread over the table (rather than concentrated in a few blocks) and not in cache, fetching 249 rows could mean well over 200 disk requests. If your I/O subsystem is busy or has poor performance (a single 7200 rpm desktop-class disk for instance), that can easily take over 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on MySQL, but it looks to me like it's doing a table scan by secid_date, which isn't even in the query at all. And scanning 17M rows is not what you want to be doing unless you really have to.

Check your indexes

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM financial_key_ratios\G
```

I would make sure that you have something like

```
+-----------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+ ... 
| Table                 | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | ... 
+-----------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------+ ... 
| financial_key_ratios  |          1 | ...        |            1 | SecurityId    | ...
```

and if possible

```
| financial_key_ratios  |          1 | ...        |            2 | DateModified  | ...
```

If you aren't indexing on at least SecurityId, you can add it with

```
CREATE INDEX IdxSecurityId ON financial_key_ratios (SecurityId)
```

You can take it a step further and include DateModified

```
CREATE INDEX IdxSecurityId_DateModified ON financial_key_ratios (SecurityId, DateModified)
```

Comment: `secid_date`  suggest he already has the last index

Comment: [Indexing Cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) -- that would come to the same conclusion.

Comment: It was worth a shot as a potential solution since the original post was vague on what indexes existed as well as the intermittency of the issue.